# drawing concentric squares using TurtleGraphics

Tags: java, geometry, turtle-graphics

okay im trying to draw concentric squares using turtlegraphics, but i cannot figure out how to make the squares not touch each other on one side. any help ?

http://i51.tinypic.com/34gly7b.png

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
       int i,A,M;
       A=0;
       M=0;



        StandardPen pen = new StandardPen();
           //RainbowPen pen = new RainbowPen();
            //WigglePen pen = new WigglePen();
            //WiggleRainbowPen pen = new WiggleRainbowPen();

            pen.setColor(Color.green);
            pen.setWidth(5);


    for (i=1;i<=4;i++){
            A=A+20;
            M=M+40;
            pen.up();
            pen.move(A,A);

            pen.down();

            pen.turn(45);
            pen.move(M);
            pen.turn(90);
            pen.move(M);
            pen.turn(90);
            pen.move(M);

            pen.turn(90);
            pen.move(M);

            pen.up();
```

Comment: you could just move the starting position of a new square right after pen.up(). there are various ways of doing this, like pen.up, move(M/10).

Answer (score 0):

try to translate this "turtle pseudo code" to your java code

```
reset
$startX = 100
$startY = 100
$length = 20


gox $startX
goy $startY

turnleft 45

repeat(4) {

    repeat(4) {
        # this draws the actual square
        forward $length
        turnleft 90
    }

    # move half the square size away 
    penup
    turnright 90
    forward $length / 2
    turnright 90
    forward $length / 2
    turnright 180
    pendown

    #define the size for the next square
    $length = $length * 2
}
```

Comment: adding the pen.move(M/4); threw it off more... here's what it gave me after adding that http://i55.tinypic.com/23iez3n.png

Comment: try placing it before the last "pen.turn(90);"  meanwhile i will try to reproduce this with a language im more familiar with

Comment: that didn't work either, i modified the code just a bit to fit the requirements of my teacher but still having the same problem.. ill edit the code above

Comment: now i see the the problem, your first turn is only 45, you could do that outside of the for look if you just want the whole square rotated.  btw, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? drawing a spiral or perfect squares?

Comment: after the pen.move(A,A); the angle has to be 45.. if not the square is sideways.. it has to be perfect squares and the first one has to be at (20,20) and the next at (40,40) and the next at (80,80).. the squares have to be inside each other and not touch.. all having a center point of (0,0) but each square being 4 moves longer then the last square. hope i didnt confuse you..

Comment: actually i think you are just confusing yourself with the for loop. just split up the task your teacher gave you in smaler easier tasks. first learn how to create a square(you can use a function for that that just has the length of a side as input), then try to position that square at the center, i.e. by using "originatingPosition minus sizeOfSquare" as a starting position for the turtle. if that works think about sizing the square up and finaly add the 45 degrees turn at the beginning of the code. hope that helps :)

Comment: im sorry i forgot to mention that each square has to be made with just a single for-loop, ive made a grid on the canvas that is helping me visualize where it has to move but i cannot get it to move right, ive split up the variables to x&y so i can manipulate the movements alittle better.. but still the same problem & ive already done the assignment without the for-loop i just cant do it with it =/

Comment: is there no command to move back to the center? you could just go to the center after each square and start a new one at the position of e.g. "centerX" minus "squareSize"

Comment: now i have a solution in turtle (the logo one) i will post it as anwer and it can serve you as pseudo code, just translate it in java and it should work

Comment: Okay thanks, I'm not On my computer right now but tomorrow I'll change my code... I think I know what I have to do

Comment: all i needed was a simple 90 turn in between the 45 and the move.. lol